# Is there a way to have two keyboard shortcuts for the same function?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, shortcuts-app

I saw these instructions to replace a shortcut

> On your Mac, choose Apple menu > System Preferences, click Keyboard, then click Shortcuts. Select App Shortcuts on the left, click the Add button , click the Application pop-up menu, then choose a specific app or All Applications.

So I can add a shortcut named 'Copy' under all applications, and insert <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as the keystroke. But then <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> won't work as the Copy shortcut anymore.

Is there a way to have both?

Comment: Maybe I am misreading the question, but you **already** have both. `cmd` + `C` is copy and `cmd` + `v` is insert. If your question is, whether one can have one shortcut for two different things, the answer is **no**. How would that even work?

Comment: @X_841 - OP is asking about ctrl/c and cmd/c accessing the **same** command, not one shortcut to 2 different commands.

Comment: Now I get it thanks! Seems quite unecessary to me so I didnt think about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Shortcuts Prefs won't allow you to add the same Menu item twice, so no, this cannot be done.

Additionally, in Finder, the Copy menu item is a 'smart' structure, meaning it always contains the name or count of what would be copied by the key command. You cannot use the shortcut replacer at all on a smart menu.

Examples…

[image][image]

Furthermore, attempting to override a system-wide command like Copy is bound to fail somewhere. It's definitely best to stick to the system defaults for such as those.

Comment: What is a smart menu?

Comment: Contextual menu.

Comment: Some people have accessibility issues where cmd+<key> is problematic. Assigning it to a single keystroke FN key, can be helpful, for example. So, no, it's not "definitely best" to stick to the system defaults. It's hardly catastrophic if "Copy [shortcut] is bound to fail somewhere" vs the benefit of reassignment that will work in 99.9% of cases.

Comment: @John - it's literally impossible to add 2 key commands as the OP wanted, or add one to a contextual menu. As to the rest, I'm not addressing accessibility concerns, but technical ones.